# Copying data from S3 to Redshift stuck

Tags: amazon-redshift, endpoint, vpc

I have a redshift cluster in private subnet, I have attached an IAM role with the policy of full permission to S3.
But sill copy or unload command stuck and finally got timed out error, any thought?
Seems I have to modify some network or connectivity changes.

Comment: Is there a route to S3 from your subnet?  Do you have an S3 endpoint defined?

Comment: The issue has been fixed by adding S3 endpoint and update route tables